# Issues with Oracle JDBC with Hibernate... Sometimes

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a bit of a unique issue.

I'm able to successfully connect and manage entities when running JUnit tests, but once I start my actual application, I get "Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver class not found."

What confuses me is that it is there. It **works** when running my JUnit Tests.

Any insights are appreciated!

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="db">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">db</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="org/entity/RunResultEntity.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/entity/TransactionResultEntity.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="org/entity/FailureResultEntity.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package org.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.*;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()
            ).buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Exception thrown here!
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

pom.xml (dependency added to local repository)

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
   <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

log

```
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:58 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:58 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:58 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: org/entity/RunResultEntity.hbm.xml
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: org/entity/TransactionResultEntity.hbm.xml
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: org/entity/FailureResultEntity.hbm.xml
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:59 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: db
Oct 09, 2014 3:02:59 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver class not found
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. Lower in my pom.xml I had this little snippet

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

The classifier was only giving access to my test suite. Removing the classifier fixed the issue.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```